# Conditional Formatting based on different cells

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I have an Excel sheet where if in the range ColumnsA:F one row has any value or text then G's below cell color green:

```
A     B     C     D     E     F       G

xyz  xyz    xyz   xyz   xyz   xyz     OK
```

Answer (score 1):

Please select ColumnG, HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*, **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=COUNTA($A1:$F1)<>0
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd> select green, OK, OK.